# com.deliveryrunner.vendor.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android application made with flutter, in older versions I've used `firebase_messaging` which required me to change my `MainActivity` file to `Application` with some edits mentioned below to be able to handle background messages. and it worked fine back then.

Here is the old `Application` file :

```java
package com.deliveryrunner.vendor;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }

}
```

Now after upgrading to the latest version of flutter and `firebase_messaging` they mentioned in the documentation that I don't need this anymore and I can go back to normal `MainACtivity` and I did that. here is the `MainActivity` file :

```kotlin
package com.deliveryrunner.vendor

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {}
```

please note that i am changing the entry in `AndroidManifest.xml` whenever i change the file:

```xml
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
```

```xml
    <application
        android:name=".MainActivity"
```

finally, after upgrading whenever I run the app I get this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14596): Process: com.deliveryrunner.vendor, PID: 14596
E/AndroidRuntime(14596): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.deliveryrunner.vendor.MainActivity: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.deliveryrunner.vendor.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1244)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6683)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.deliveryrunner.vendor.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1158)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1236)
E/AndroidRuntime(14596):    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please remove this line from the Application tag

```
<application
    android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Or

```
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity"
```

Add the line inside the activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Similar to this code

```
 <application
    android:label="..."
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
```

This code is work in my case.

Answer (score 6):

Please remove this line from the Application tag

```
<application
    android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Add the line inside the activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: For me it was solved with replacing "${applicationName}" with ".MainActivity" in the <activity> tag